# Implement BST using Scala Pattern Matching

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and was trying to implement a BST using Pattern Matching Concept in scala.

Edit: I have modified the insert function and now it is behaving in the expected manner, can someone help me to make it tail recursive?
Also, any other code improvements would be appreciated.

```
trait IntTree {                                                                                                                                   
  def contains(v: Int): Boolean                                                                                                                   

  def insert(x: Int): IntTree                                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                                 

case object EmptyTree extends IntTree {                                                                                                           

  override def insert(x: Int): IntTree = Node(x, EmptyTree, EmptyTree)                                                                            

  override def contains(v: Int): Boolean = false                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                 

case class Node(elem: Int, left: IntTree, right: IntTree) extends IntTree {                                                                       

  override def contains(v: Int): Boolean = {                                                                                                      
    @scala.annotation.tailrec                                                                                                                     
    def contains(t: IntTree, v: Int): Boolean = t match {                                                                                         
      case Node(data, _, _) if (data == v) => true                                                                                                
      case Node(data, l, r) => if (data > v) contains(l, v) else contains(r, v)                                                                   
      case _ => false                                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                             

    contains(this, v)                                                                                                                             
  }                                                                                                                                               

  override def insert(x: Int): IntTree = {                                                                                                        
    def insert(t: IntTree, x: Int): IntTree = t match {                                                                                           
      case Node(data, l, r) if (data > x) => Node(data, insert(l, x), r)                                                                          
      case Node(data, l, r) if (data < x) => Node(data, l, insert(r, x))                                                                          
      case EmptyTree => t insert x                                                                                                                
      case _ => t                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                             

    insert(this, x)                                                                                                                               
  }                                                                                                                                               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would require a revisit and update of the parent nodes after you go down the leaf:

```
sealed trait IntTree {
    def contains(v: Int): Boolean
    def insert(x: Int): Node // better to return Node here
}

def insert(x: Int): Node = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def insert(t: IntTree, x: Int, parents: List[Node]): Node = t match {
        case EmptyTree =>
            parents.foldLeft(t insert x) { case (n, p) =>
                if (p.elem >= n.elem) p.copy(left = n)
                else p.copy(right = n)
            }
        case Node(data, l, r) =>
            insert(if(data >= x) l else r, x, t :: parents)
    }

    insert(this, x, List.empty)
}
```